# GLFW Window Close

Tags: haskell, graphics, window, glfw

I'm running on x86_64 Arch Linux with X11 and xfce4 and trying to compile a simple OpenGL/GLFW application with OpenGL and GLFW-b libraries. I'm having trouble with getting the window to close, though - I can only kill it with Ctrl-C.

Code at http://pastebin.com/i7Zshfk1

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an infinite loop in your main function. Even if the main window is closed, you'll still have the main update loop running in the background. You can solve the problem by using a main loop like this:

```
mainLoop = do
  drawFrame
  swapBuffers

  -- Check if window is still open
  isOpen <- windowIsOpen
  -- Call mainLoop recursively
  when isOpen mainLoop
```

You should then call the `mainLoop` function instead of the `forever $ do ...` loop.

Note also that you should be careful about FPS limiting; you will screw up automatic vsync that might be controlled by your driver or GLFW options. Just calling `swapBuffers` as fast as you can is almost always better.

Comment: Can't seem to find a simple way to write windowIsOpen, which isn't defined in GLFW or GLFW-b

Comment: It is defined in [`GLFW-b`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/GLFW-b/latest/doc/html/Graphics-UI-GLFW.html#v:windowIsOpen)

Comment: You're completely right - I was looking for isWindowOpen. *Embarrassing*.
Then this works great, if GLFW cleanup code is added (GLFW.closeWindow and GLFW.terminate)